# Find the elements of a matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I know this is a very simple example, and I guess the solution is something very easy, but I just can't quite understand what exactly should be done in the task and what approach should I take:
[image: task]

Is it something with co-factor expansion or just creating a simple augmented matrix and reducing it to ech.form ? Give me some clues, please.

Comment: Write $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21}& a_{22} \end{bmatrix}$, find the products and you have a system of equations.

Comment: Alternately, write the above equations as $A {\bf x}_i = {\bf y}_i$; then, we can write both equations simultaneously as $A X = Y$, where $X = [{\bf x}_1 \,{\bf x}_2]$ and $Y = [{\bf y}_1 \,{\bf y}_2]$. Now, $X$ is invertible, so $A = YX^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$. Then your two conditions yield
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\7\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{align} a+2b&=-1\\ c+2d&=7\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-1\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{align} -a+b&=-2\\ -c+d&=-1\end{align}.
$$

Solve these 4 equations in the 4 unknowns to obtain $a=1$, $b=-1$, $c=3$, $d=2$.